# systemctl shows service file not-found, even though .service file is present

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I am running into a weird issue. I have a service file to start a custom application. systemctl command shows LOAD as not-found

> resource-service-prod-prod.service   not-found active running   resource-service-prod-prod.service

however, file is shown in

```
ls -lrt /etc/systemd/system
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   96 Mar  5  2017 resource-service-prod.service -> /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/bin/resource-service-prod-prod.service
```

service status shows as running, but loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)

```
sudo service resource-service-prod status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status resource-service-prod.service
● resource-service-prod-prod.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-12-20 06:40:37 CST; 3 weeks 0 days ago
 Main PID: 12888 (node)
   CGroup: /system.slice/resource-service-prod-prod.service
           ├─12888 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12923 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12924 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12930 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12936 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12942 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12943 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12949 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12960 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12961 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12972 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           ├─12978 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
           └─12984 /usr/bin/node /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/source/app.js
```

Application stops on issuing service stop, but while trying to start back, it wont (since file not found). Doing a `systemctl daemon-reload` helps start back the service and service file is shown as loaded. Any idea why this kind of a behaviour ?

actual service file is on a separate mount and it is a symlink in `/etc/systemd/system`

Comment: OK, so where did the service file go?

Comment: service file is present in the path /opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/bin/resource-service-prod-prod.service and symlink is also present (not broken) /etc/systemd/system/resource-service-prod.service ... Problem is systemctl shows LOAD as not-found for this service. systemctl daemon-reload after stopping the service shows LOAD as active ....

Answer (score 5):

I know this is several months old, but for the record, also check the config file for the service. You can get this message because a dependency unit was not found. Systemd doesn't seem to give enough detail in the error message where it differentiates between the main unit you are starting and a dependent unit. Sometimes it will work around these issues at boot and then fail if you do it manually, which is quite maddening.

Comment: +1 beer from my part. This is maddening for sure. In my case it was a missing mysql.service that caused my hand made service to just error out that it's not there :-/

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the service file was moved away while the service was running. You may need to run `systemctl daemon-reload`. Of course, verify the file `/opt/app/daps-prod/resource-service/bin/resource-service-prod-prod.service` is actually there.

```
[root@storage system]# systemctl status smb.service
● smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
...
[root@storage system]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@storage system]# systemctl status smb.service
● smb.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
...
[root@storage system]# ln -s /opt/smb.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/smb.service
[root@storage system]# systemctl status smb.service
● smb.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
...
[root@storage system]# systemctl daemon-reload
[root@storage system]# systemctl status smb.service
● smb.service - Samba SMB Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/opt/smb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
```

Comment: i am running systemctl daemon-reload after stopping the service. That brings back the service file as LOAD active in systemctl. My question is why would it turn to Not-found (this is seen happening on 4 servers). There are no changes done on these servers while the application is started. Does having /opt as a separate mount got something to do with this kind of a behaviour ?

Comment: It should not change _on its own_ - I would suggest creating an audit rule against the directory/file to see if something is making changes to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue on Amazon Linux.

Following worked for me

- Instead of creating service file directly in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/`,  I created service file in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, like `/usr/lib/systemd/system/abc.service`
- I then created a  link -
  `ln  -sf /usr/lib/systemd/system/cerncshnbdr01-abc.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/abc.service`
- Then I was able  to enable the service  - `systemctl enable abc.service`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, .service was on a 2nd partition on the same disk,
it worked great, but after restart I always got the not-found message.
I guess 2nd partition was delayed milliseconds after boot.

The solution was to copy .service to system partition (/etc/) and install from there.

It's crazy to know that a production server can be this fragile with systemd.
Since than I moved to supervisord, never looking back.